# Creating accordions without using repetitive functions

Tags: javascript

I'm writing code for some accordions at the moment, using some simple vanilla JS (strictly not jQuery, has to be vanilla) and it feels like my code is really inefficient.

Here it is at the moment:

```js
// Variables
    
    let down = document.getElementById("chevron-down-1");
    let down2 = document.getElementById("chevron-down-2");
    let up = document.getElementById("chevron-up-1");
    let up2 = document.getElementById("chevron-up-2");
    let drop = document.getElementById("dropdown-1");
    let drop2 = document.getElementById("dropdown-2");
    
    // Functions
    
    let open = function() {
      down.style.display = "none";
      up.style.display = "block";
      drop.style.display = "block";
    };
    
    let close = function() {
      down.style.display = "block";
      up.style.display = "none";
      drop.style.display = "none";
    };
    
    let open2 = function() {
      down2.style.display = "none";
      up2.style.display = "block";
      drop2.style.display = "block";
    };
    
    let close2 = function() {
      down2.style.display = "block";
      up2.style.display = "none";
      drop2.style.display = "none";
    };
    
    // Event Listeners
    
    down.addEventListener('click', open);
    down2.addEventListener('click', open2);
    
    up.addEventListener('click', close);
    up2.addEventListener('click', close2);
```

```css
    .accordion-container {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-around;
      flex-direction: column;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
    }
    
    .accordion {
      height: auto;
      width: 90%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      background-color: #999;
      box-shadow: 5px 10px 5px #888888;
    }
    
    .accordion-1 {
      height: 30%;
      width: 90%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-around;
    }
    
    #chevron-down-1 {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    #chevron-up-1 {
      cursor: pointer;
      display: none;
    }
    
    #dropdown-1 {
      width: 80%;
      display: none;
    }
    
    .accordion-2 {
      height: 30%;
      width: 90%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: space-around;
    }
    
    #chevron-down-2 {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    #chevron-up-2 {
      cursor: pointer;
      display: none;
    }
    
    #dropdown-2 {
      width: 80%;
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
      <div class="accordion-container">
        <div class="accordion">
          <div class="accordion-1">
            <h2>Click here</h2>
            <i id="chevron-down-1" class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
            <i id="chevron-up-1" class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
          </div>
          <p id="dropdown-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion">
          <div class="accordion-2">
            <h2>Click here</h2>
            <i id="chevron-down-2" class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
            <i id="chevron-up-2" class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
          </div>
          <p id="dropdown-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

It feels like there's a way of writing the JavaScript so I don't have to write new functions for each new accordion, or call each element through its ID, or add respective event listeners - but I don't know the best way to approach it.

How would you re-shape this code to reduce the repetition?

Answer (score 1):

The code can be re-written so that you don't have to write new functions. The relevant `functions`, `ids` and `classes` are there but actual power of those is not utilized. The following pointers can be noted while re-writing:

- The common functionalities for accordions can be clubbed via classes
- The common CSS for the accordion can be clubbed via classes
- There can be n number of accordions with `different ids` to uniquely identify each one of them and then `the inside html structure can be identical`
- While writing functions; classes, ids etc can also be passed as arguments to make generic functions

Considering these, the code can be re-written as:

```js
let open = function(accordion) {
  accordion.getElementsByClassName("fa-chevron-down")[0].style.display = "none";
  accordion.getElementsByClassName("fa-chevron-up")[0].style.display = "block";
  accordion.getElementsByClassName("dropdown")[0].style.display = "block";
};

let close = function(accordion) {
  accordion.getElementsByClassName("fa-chevron-down")[0].style.display = "block";
  accordion.getElementsByClassName("fa-chevron-up")[0].style.display = "none";
  accordion.getElementsByClassName("dropdown")[0].style.display = "none";
};


document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-container")[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("fa-chevron-down")) {
    open(e.target.parentNode.parentNode)
  }
  if (e.target.classList.contains("fa-chevron-up")) {
    close(e.target.parentNode.parentNode)
  }
})
```

```css
.accordion-container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.accordion-wrap {
  height: auto;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #999;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 5px #888888;
}

.accordion {
  height: 30%;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.fa-chevron-down {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-chevron-up {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  width: 80%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion-container">
  <div class="accordion-wrap">
    <div class="accordion">
      <h2>Click here</h2>
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-down">></i>
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-up">^</i>
    </div>
    <p class="dropdown">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-wrap">
    <div class="accordion">
      <h2>Click here</h2>
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-down">></i>
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-up">^</i>
    </div>
    <p class="dropdown">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here you can add `n` number of accordions. Same `open` and `close` function will be used.

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts/clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you just need one handler (snippet: `toggleAccordeonElement`) to toggle the open/close state of an Accord**e**on. 
If the clickable element has a `data-attribute` (snippet: `data-isAccordeonToggle`) it's easy identifiable as the element to take action on within the handler (using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) here). Find the closest `.accordion`-element and from that identify the elements to toggle the display value. Create an array of the elements identified and apply the toggle routing (based on the current style) for each of those elements.

I have also reduced the number of css-classes in the snippet, and added a class name `dropdown` for the '#dropdown-[n]` elements.

```js
const toggleAccordeonElement = evt => {
  const origin = evt.target;
  if (origin.dataset.isaccordeontoggle) {
    const localRoot = origin.closest(".accordion");
    [localRoot.querySelector(`.fa-chevron-down`),
      localRoot.querySelector(`.fa-chevron-up`),
      localRoot.querySelector(`.dropdown`)
    ].forEach(elem => {
      const currentDisplayStyle = getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue("display");
      elem.style.display = currentDisplayStyle === "none" ? "block" : "none";
      origin.dataset.isaccordeontoggle = origin.dataset.isaccordeontoggle === "Open" 
        ? "Close" : "Open";
    });

  }
};

document.addEventListener('click', toggleAccordeonElement);
```

```css
.accordion-container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.accordion {
  height: auto;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #999;
  box-shadow: 5px 10px 5px #888888;
}

.accordionInner {
  height: 30%;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.fas.fa-chevron-down {
  display: block;
}

.fas.fa-chevron-up {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  width: 80%;
  display: none;
}

.accordion H2 {
  cursor: pointer;
}

[data-isaccordeontoggle]:before {
  content: attr(data-isaccordeontoggle)
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="accordion-container">
  <div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordionInner">
      <h2 data-isAccordeonToggle="Open"></h2>
      <i id="chevron-down-1" class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
      <i id="chevron-up-1" class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
    </div>
    <p id="dropdown-1" class="dropdown">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion">
    <div class="accordionInner">
      <h2 data-isAccordeonToggle="Open"></h2>
      <i id="chevron-down-2" class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
      <i id="chevron-up-2" class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
    </div>
    <p id="dropdown-2" class="dropdown">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to always keep all my styling inside my css (unless you need to calculate something dynamically like a height, but that isn't the case here). This way you always know where to look for stuff, and css is clearly meant for styling.

All you really need to do is toggle the state of your accordion when it is clicked, and the state defines the way it is displayed. That could be as simple as toggling a class on the accordion wrapper. Something like this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.accordion header').forEach(trigger => {
  trigger.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.currentTarget.parentNode.classList.toggle('open');
  });
});
```

```css
.accordion header {
  background: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fa-chevron-down {
  display: none;
}

.accordion-content {
  display: none;
}

.accordion.open .accordion-content {
  display: block;
}

.accordion.open .fa-chevron-up {
  display: none;
}
.accordion.open .fa-chevron-down {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
 <div class="accordion-container">
        <article class="accordion">
          <header>
            <h2>Click here</h2>
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-down">+</i>
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-up">-</i>
          </header>
          <p class="accordion-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </article>
        <article class="accordion">
          <header>
            <h2>Click here</h2>
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-down">+</i>
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-up">-</i>
          </header>
          <p class="accordion-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </article>
      </div>
```

(note that I reduced the css to the essential parts for clarity)

Now you can add as many `.accordion` elements as you want without having to update your javascript, as long as you maintain the same structure. And no need for ID's either.